# How to copy value into array element correctly?

Tags: c

I need an universal function that will put a value into array, I wrote it so:

```
int add_element(void** arr, void* val, int t_size, int* size, int* capacity) {

    if ((*size) == (*capacity)) {
        *capacity += ARRAY_INC;
        *arr = (char*)realloc(*arr, (*capacity) * sizeof(char));

        if (*arr == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    memcpy(*arr + ((*size)++), val, t_size);

    return 0;
}
```

It works perfect for a char array but I have troubles with array of structures in the next code:

```
int scan_tokens(Token** p_tokens, int* size) {
    char* line;
    int len;

    if (get_line(&line, &len)) {
        return 1;
    }

    int capacity = ARRAY_INC;
    *size = 0;
    *p_tokens = (Token*)malloc(capacity * sizeof(Token));
    int start = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        char ch = line[i];

        if (isdigit(ch)) {

            if(start == -1) {
                start = i;
            }
        } else {
            if (start != -1) {
                Token t;
                int count = i - start;
                t.size = count;
                t.data.token = (char*)malloc(count * sizeof(char));
                memcpy(t.data.token, line + start, count * sizeof(char));
                start = -1;
                add_element(p_tokens, &t, sizeof(Token), size, &capacity);
            }

            Token t;

            switch(ch) {
                case SUM:
                case SUB:
                case MUL:
                case DIV:
                case LBR:
                case RBR:
                    t.size = 0;
                    t.data.ch = ch;
                    add_element(p_tokens, &t, sizeof(Token), size, &capacity);
                    break;
                default:
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (start != -1) {
        Token t;
        int count = len - start;
        t.size = count;
        t.data.token = (char*)malloc(count * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(t.data.token, line + start, count * sizeof(char));
        start = -1;
        // Will a copy of `t` in p_tokens be reseted on the next iteration?
        add_element(p_tokens, &t, sizeof(Token), size, &capacity);
    }

    free(line);
    line = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that added element of array was reset on the next iteration of loop. And I can't get why? When I call `memcpy` in `add_element` it must copy all fields of `Token` structure in related fields of array element structures, it isn't?
What do I doing wrong and how to fix? I can't get already...

**FIXED SECONDARY ERROR**

```
int add_element(void** arr, void* val, int t_size, int* size, int* capacity) {

    if ((*size) == (*capacity)) {
        *capacity += ARRAY_INC;
        *arr = realloc(*arr, (*capacity) * t_size);

        if (*arr == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    memcpy(*arr + ((*size)++), val, t_size);

    return 0;
}
```

The code still has same problem.
**ADDED**
Seems I got my error, it's here `*arr + ((*size)++)`: `arr` is `void**` so maybe `(*arr + some_num)` will give a wrong offset but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `capacity` means capacity in terms of "nr of elements", not capacity in terms of bytes, right? Then something like `(*capacity) * sizeof(char)` is suspicious...

Comment: @StephanLechner, thank you very much, I didn't notice when I rewrote from `char`.

Comment: @xing, `arr` is a pointer to the pointer of array. I.e. `*arr` is a pointer to the first element of array.

Comment: You should get a compilation error for the call `add_element(p_tokens, &t, sizeof(Token), size, &capacity);`.  There is no implicit conversion from `Token**` to `void**` and this is a bug in your code. If you don't see an error then reconfigure your compiler

Comment: Also `*arr +` is an error, you cannot do arithmetic on `void *`

Comment: @M.M, yeah, u are right, thank you... Imma noobie in C yet. But how to realize then? Is it possible to cast to `char*` and make offset like `(((char*)(*arr)) + some_num * type_size)`?

Comment: It works, 2 hours of problems and it works =) Thank you all for help

Comment: Yes you can cast to `char*`. But the aliasing problem still remains. It'd be better to accept `void *` argument and return the change value as `void *`

Comment: @M.M, thank you, I will =)

Answer (score 4):

In `scan_tokens` you have the initial allocation:

```
*p_tokens = malloc(capacity * sizeof(Token));
```

<sub>[Unnecessary cast removed]</sub>

Here you allocate `capacity * sizeof(Token)` bytes.

Then in `add_element` you have:

```
*arr = realloc(*arr, (*capacity) * sizeof(char));
```

Here you allocate `*capacity` bytes.

This is of course not correct and will most likely allocate to little. In the `add_element` function you should allocate a multiple of `t_size` bytes:

```
*arr = realloc(*arr, (*capacity) * t_size);
```

---

On a very related note: Don't reassign back to the pointer you pass to the [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) function. If `realloc` fails it will return a null pointer, leading to you losing the original pointer. Use a temporary variable that you check before assigning.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's really my error... But it still doesn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for help, I got my error. Below a correct variant of my function:

```
int add_element(void** arr, void* val, int t_size, int* size, int* capacity) {

    if ((*size) == (*capacity)) {
        *capacity += ARRAY_INC;
        *arr = realloc(*arr, (*capacity) * t_size);

        if (*arr == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    memcpy((char*)(*arr) + (*size) * t_size, (char*)val, t_size);
    ++(*size);

    return 0;
}
```

I was need to cast my `void` pointer to `char` pointer.